# Как подключиться к wifi с помощью wps?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Есть нетбук под *ubuntu 14 lts*, есть роутер с *wifi* и *wps*, пароль неизвестен, но известны *wps-pin* и *mac-адрес*.

Как подключиться к *wifi*, нажав кнопку *wps* на роутере?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/170799/416190

Answer (score 2):

вольный перевод [ответа](https://askubuntu.com/a/170799/416190) на вопрос: [How to connect to Wi-Fi AP through WPS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/120367/416190) с учётом [этой](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) информации (далее подразумевается, что *wifi*-интерфейс у вас называется `wlan0`):

1. создайте (или отредактируйте) файл `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`, приведя его к виду:

   ```
   ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
   ctrl_interface_group=0
   update_config=1
   ```
2. запустите программу *wpa_supplicant* в режиме демона:

   ```
   $ sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
   ```
3. запустите программу *wpa_cli*:

   ```
   $ sudo wpa_cli
   ```

   и убедитесь, что она работает, введя в её приглашении команду `status`. вы должны увидеть ответ `wpa_state=INACTIVE`.
4. используйте команды `scan` и `scan_results` для сканирования доступных беспроводных сетей:

   ```
   > scan
   OK
   <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
   > scan_results
   bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
   00:00:00:00:00:00 2462 -49 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS] MYSSID
   11:11:11:11:11:11 2437 -64 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS] ANOTHERSSID
   ```
5. добавьте выбранный *bssid* (`00:00:00:00:00:00` — для `MYSSID`) и *pin* (который вам известен, для примера: `12345678`):

   ```
   > wps_reg 00:00:00:00:00:00 12345678
   ```

   вы должны получить ответ "ok". подождите несколько секунд, пока *wpa_supplicant* связывается с роутером, проводит *association* и *key negotiation*. если вы увидите сообщение `CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED`, значит, *pin* принят и *association* прошла удачно.
   в данный момент вы можете запустить (в другом терминале)

   ```
   $ sudo dhclient wlan0
   ```

   для проверки, что *dhcpd* в роутере нормально функционирует, и вы можете получить от него ip-адрес для интерфейса *wlan0*.

   вернитесь опять к запущенной программе *wpa_cli* и введите команду `save`, которая должна вернуть "ok" и сохранить новые настройки в файле `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`.
6. проверьте эти настройки, и, если всё в порядке, вы должны увидеть в описании новой сети строку, начинающуюся с `psk`. это и будет сгенерированный ключ.

далее можно будет подключаться к тому же роутеру уже «обычным» способом: из командной строки, из *gui*-«обёртки» вокруг *network-manager-а* и т.п.